When the image of flipping and flipped loci of a dlt pair are the same?
I'm learning the birational geometry and I have the following elementary question but it seems no books talk about it:

Let $(X,B)$ be a DLT pair (with $\mathbb{R}$-coefficients), assume we have a flipping contraction $f:X\to Y$ and assume the flip $f^+:X^+\to Y$ exists. Then may we have $f(\mathrm{Exc}(f))=f^+(\mathrm{Exc}(f^+))$ (as sets)? If not, when is this comes true?

When $X$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial and $B$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor, then we have
$$
X^+\cong\mathrm{Proj}_Y \bigoplus_{m\geq 0}f_*\mathscr{O}_X(\left\lfloor m(K_X+B)\right\rfloor).
$$
Maybe in this case we can have this property?

Thank you for your any help!

The answer have been appeared in the comment of this question. Now I move it to here:
For any $y\in f(\mathrm{Exc}(f))$, it is no longer $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial near $y\in Y$, hence $X^+\to Y$ is not isomorphic near $y$. Thus $y\in f^+(\mathrm{Exc}(f^+))$. The inverse direction can be seen similarly.
